# Evaluating $\int\frac1{\sqrt{12x + 0.02x^2}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I faced this strange integral while solving mechanics homework.
I couldn't proceed further.

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{12x + 0.02x^2}}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{2\sqrt x\sqrt{x + 600}\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(0.0408248\sqrt x\right)}{\sqrt{12x + 0.02x^2}} + C$$

I'd like to know how to get this solution; I tried integration by parts and integration by substitution, but all in vain.

Comment: Try completing the square first.  Then a substitution might be easier.

Comment: Did you try completing the square for the expression underneath the square root sign?

Comment: I tried everything

Comment: Then show us how far you got.  Edit your work into the question.

Comment: $u$ substitution. $\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12x+.02x^2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{.02}}\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{12/.02+x}}$. Let $a=\sqrt{12/.02}$. Then ignoring the factor of $.02$, this is just $\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+x}}$. Now integrate by substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often the case that integrals of the form $$\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v^2 \pm(\text{stuff})}}$$ can be solved through trigonometric means. Your integral is no different. Notice that $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{12x + 0.02x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{50}(x+300)^2-1800}} \\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{50}}\sqrt{(x+300)^2-90000}} \\ = \frac{\sqrt{50}}{300\sqrt{\left(\frac{x+300}{300}\right)^2-1}}\end{align}$$ Now if $u = \frac{x+300}{300}$ then $du = \frac{1}{300}dx$. Hence, $$\int\frac1{\sqrt{12x + 0.02x^2}}\,\mathrm dx  = \sqrt{50}\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} $$ You should recognize $\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}} $ as the derivative of one of the inverse trig functions (albeit a hyperbolic one). Once you know which one, you will have an extremely easy antiderivative to get your answer.